waitForEvent console playwright not working
I have the following playwright code
await page.waitForEvent("console", msg => msg.text().includes("TEST: test 1 objects."));

In the code, I do console.log("TEST: test 1 objects") when someone clicks on a button but that's not being picked up by plawyright.
I'm I missing something?

The "when someone" is a click call in your code?

Yes it’s a click call @hardkoded

If you are causing that log line you might need to wait for the console line while you click. Something like this:
await Promise.all([
  page.waitForEvent("console", msg => msg.text().includes("TEST: test 1 objects.")),
  page.locator('someLocator').click()
]);

